# Is there an alternative to .toggle() that will let me control on/off?

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a portfolio website and I want to be able to tag items in the page that displays work so you can toggle visibility. I have it set up with .toggle() right now, which works, except that if I want to use multiple tags, it throws off other tags. You an see this is action on my site - http://nu-creative.com/ourwork.html

On the left, you can toggle both branding and case studies, but the third image is tagged as both, so when you click one after the other it hides it when it should show it and vice versa.

The code is all in the bottom of the page but a snippet of the relevant jQuery is here:

```
        $("#branding").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("showItem");
            $(".brandingHide").toggle("slow", function () {

            });
        }); 


        $("#case").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("showItem");
            $(".caseHide").toggle("slow", function () {

            });
        });
```

Then the <-li> has the appropriate ID and the class is on the div in the grid that hides. I could make it work if I had two buttons - a hide and a show, but that would be weird. I could also hack it by making the grey a seperate layer so that when you click again you are actually clicking a different item which then disappears and exposes the show button again. There must be a better way, though!

Thanks in advance!

***Solution***

http://jsfiddle.net/ngau3xjL/5/

Comment: Set up a JSFiddle demonstrating what you want to do (or as close as you can get.)

Comment: ... or don't use `toggle`? Just use `hide/show`.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this UX is confusing.

Comment: I know the UI is confusing in this example, fortunately this is not the end product. I'll set up a jsFiddle. If you know how to make one button work as both hide and show, that would be what I need, though. I just haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Just test whether you are hiding or showing. You toggle the "showItem" class, so you can use that to tell which action it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to complete your animation logic. The advantage of this approach is its more verbose but still only one DOM lookup.

```
   $("#branding").click(function () {
       var $element = $(this);
       var isVisible = $element.hasClass('showItem');
       if(isVisible)
           $element.removeClass("showItem");
       } else {
           $element.addClass("showItem");
       }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngau3xjL/4/

Comment: This doesn't work but I feel like this is the right direction. I click and it does nothing. I'm setting up a jsFiddle as Mathletics suggested.

Comment: @FeiLauren just add the `hide` and `show` to the `if` and `else` clauses here and you're done.

Comment: I feel derpy. Not working for me. The jsFiddle is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ngau3xjL/
And my attempt to make that work is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ngau3xjL/1/
I think it might be a simple logic thing because my structure and naming mechanisms don't make as much sense now as they did with the initial structure. Sorry about that.

Comment: You have your show/hide backwards, and you're missing the `{` after the `if` (check your console for errors). http://jsfiddle.net/ngau3xjL/3/

Comment: Haha, yeah you're right. Netbeans caught that, I just missed it in the fiddle. We have success! I'll add the fixed jsFiddle in the answer. High fives all around! Thank you both @Mathletics and @TysonWolker!   

Solution for reference of others: http://jsfiddle.net/ngau3xjL/5/